# C# async wat in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.0

I was using C# with .NET 4.5 until I need to make an app for windows XP, which is not supported by .NET 4.5

My question is how to make this function:

```
        private async Task<int> wait(int czas)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(czas * 1000);
            return 0;
        });
    }
```

In .NET 4.0

Comment: If it only `Sleep()`s, just delete it.

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but Microsoft released [Microsoft.Bcl.Async](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2013/04/17/microsoft-bcl-async-is-now-stable.aspx) for .NET 4.0 to get async / await with the C# 5 compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use async and await in .net 2.0, 3.0 and 3.5, if targeting .NET 3.5 is a must, you can try [AsyncBridge](https://nuget.org/packages/AsyncBridge.Net35) for .NET 3.5.

Another post of interest might be: [Using async/await without .NET Framework 4.5](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2012/10/22/using-async-await-without-net-framework-4-5.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

You can use, as stated by David, the BCL.Async in your .Net4 project in order to provide the async/await functionality. The easiest way to do this is by installing the (now stable) Microsoft.Bcl.Async Nuget Package (more info here http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/ and here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/)

Comment: I installed Bcl.Async but it dont have Task.Run method. Do you know how i can do this ?

Comment: Ok i found a solution: Task.Factory.StartNew

Comment: Keep in mind that this way, xp users will have to install .net 4.0 and KB2468871 which is another ~20mb to download. 

Also keep in mind that the .net 4.0 bugs on xp won't be fixed and you will have no way to check them and fix if any of you xp users will have one.